# ''00:00'' format in textField (Flutter)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

[00:00 format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubun6.png)

Hello, I want to make an Interval Timer type of application as my first project in Flutter. My problem now it's the fact that I don't know how to make a textField to show minutes and seconds. I tried to use ''flutter_masked_text'' like this:

`var controller = new MaskedTextController(mask: '000.000.000-00');`

```
Row(
                         
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                              Icons.add
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 70.0,
                            height: 25.0,
                            child: TextField(controller: controller,),
                         ),
                      Icon(
                          Icons.remove
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
```

It kinda worked but not how I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace TextField widget with the following code:

```
DateTimeField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
              hintText: "Enter Time",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black,width: 2.0))
            ),
            format: _format,
            onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
              final timed = await showTimePicker(
                context: context,
                initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(currentValue ?? DateTime.now()),
              );
              return DateTimeField.convert(timed);
            },
          ),
```

And define '_format' as bellow inside the state but outside the context:

```
final _format = DateFormat("HH-mm");
```

This should help.:)

Comment: i need to install a library for this ?

Comment: YESS, add the following dependency in your pubspec,yaml file: 
      datetime_picker_formfield: "1.0.0"

Comment: it was the Visual Studio Code not saving pubspec.yaml

Comment: I still get this: 

`The method 'DateFormat' isn't defined for the type '_SetupState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DateFormat'.`

Comment: Add this too: intl: "0.16.1"

Comment: I wanted the ``00:00`` to be displayed all the time and when you press on it the keyboard would open up

Comment: Btw sorry for my english, it's not my maternal language